# start logical replication from the beginning

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand how I can start logical replication on postgres from the beginning. I'm trying to use this python library, `psycopg` (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/index.html) and have it all setup...but I'm only capturing new changes to the tables but not the current data thats in there. I'm assuming I need to specify the LSN to start at (doc: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=loggingconnection#psycopg2.extras.ReplicationMessage.data_start)...but how does one get the start of LSN?

by basic python script looks like this:

```
import json
import random
import calendar
import time
from datetime import datetime
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import LogicalReplicationConnection

my_connection  = psycopg2.connect(
                   "dbname='dbname' host='host.com' user='user' password='pass'" ,
                   connection_factory = LogicalReplicationConnection)
cur = my_connection.cursor()
cur.drop_replication_slot('wal2json_test_slot')
cur.create_replication_slot('wal2json_test_slot', output_plugin = 'wal2json')
cur.start_replication(slot_name = 'wal2json_test_slot', options = {'pretty-print' : 1}, decode= True)

def consume(msg):
    print (msg.payload)

cur.consume_stream(consume)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start streaming from a point before where the slot was created in the first place.

To get the pre-existing data, just open a second connection to the database, and read the existing data with SELECT or COPY.

Answer (score 0):

Native Logical Replication of postgresql supports the snapshot parameter on the subscription to enforce the replication to load all the selected tables/fields into the wal and perform initial load.

I am not sure if this python library supports this option of snapshot, but in any case you can construct the Replication Queries in Python Runtime and execute the from your connection to avoid any intermediate layer. This will give you more flexibility and also will be fast to adapt new PostgreSQL Replication features instead of waiting the library to adopt them.

You can start from here:

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-subscription.html#LOGICAL-REPLICATION-SUBSCRIPTION-EXAMPLES